# getting the first string character to get index?

Tags: c, sorting, indexing

I'm trying to get the alphabetic index of words in a single string. I wanted to use a `for` loop to re-use the function for the words and then store the index in an separate array and then sort them accordingly.

During compilation, the compiler is giving me an error:

```
Subscripted value is not array, pointer or vector.
```

To my basic understanding I thought that a string is an array of characters. Am I wrong?

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int findIndexOfAlphabet(char x);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {


    char word = "water";
    int number = findIndexOfAlphabet(word);
    printf("%d\n",number);


}

int findIndexOfAlphabet(char x)
{
    char trial = x[0];
    int index;
    for (int i = 'a'; i <='z'; i++)
    {
        if (trial == i)
        {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

Comment: You seem to be using `char` and `char*`interchangeably....

Comment: `char word = "water";` --> `char *word = "water";` and `char x` --> `char *x`

Comment: int findIndexOfAlphabet(char[] x)

Comment: [Array and pointer](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/)

Answer (score 1):

`x` in function `findIndexOfAlphabet` is defined as `char`, when compiled and `x[0]` is encountered the compiler is going to complain.

Declare your function appropriately:

```
int findIndexOfAlphabet(char*);
```

and, during definition:

```
int findIndexOfAlphabet(char* x)
{ 
// body similar
}
```

And `word` as `char*` and not as `char`:

```
char* word = "water";
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is correct. You defined `x` as scalar `char`

```
int findIndexOfAlphabet(char x)
```

but use it as an array:

```
char trial = x[0];
```

Comment: That identifies one of the problems. There is at least one more. And in addition to identifying the problem a good answer should also present a solution.